# How to make MongoDB use indexes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregate

I am using a copy of the **listingsAndReviews** collection from the **sample_airbnb** sample database.
I have added an index on the *address.country* field, thus when performing

```
db.listingsAndReviews.getIndexes ()
```

I get

```json
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { 'address.country': 1 },
    name: 'address_country',
    background: false,
    collation: {
      locale: 'en_US',
      caseLevel: false,
      caseFirst: 'off',
      strength: 1,
      numericOrdering: false,
      alternate: 'non-ignorable',
      maxVariable: 'punct',
      normalization: false,
      backwards: false,
      version: '57.1'
    }
  }
]
```

Now, I am trying to use the following aggregate:

```
db.listingsAndReviews.aggregate( [{ $sort: { "address.country": 1 } },
{ $project: { "address.country": 1, _id: 0 } }, 
{ $group: { _id: "$address.country", count: { $sum: 1 } } }],
{ cursor: { batchSize: 32 }, allowDiskUse: false })
```

Using *explain("executionStats")* I see that my index is not used!

```json
{
  stages: [
    {
      '$cursor': {
        queryPlanner: {
          plannerVersion: 1,
          namespace: 'mytests.listingsAndReviews',
          indexFilterSet: false,
          parsedQuery: {},
          queryHash: '6E8AB948',
          planCacheKey: '6E8AB948',
          winningPlan: {
            stage: 'SORT',
            sortPattern: { 'address.country': 1 },
            memLimit: 104857600,
            type: 'simple',
            inputStage: {
              stage: 'PROJECTION_DEFAULT',
              transformBy: { address: { country: true }, _id: false },
              inputStage: { stage: 'COLLSCAN', direction: 'forward' }
            }
          },
          rejectedPlans: []
        },
        executionStats: {
          executionSuccess: true,
          nReturned: 5555,
          executionTimeMillis: 17,
          totalKeysExamined: 0,
          totalDocsExamined: 5555,
          executionStages: {
            stage: 'SORT',
            nReturned: 5555,
            executionTimeMillisEstimate: 1,
            works: 11113,
            advanced: 5555,
            needTime: 5557,
            needYield: 0,
            saveState: 12,
            restoreState: 12,
            isEOF: 1,
            sortPattern: { 'address.country': 1 },
            memLimit: 104857600,
            type: 'simple',
            totalDataSizeSorted: 318167,
            usedDisk: false,
            inputStage: {
              stage: 'PROJECTION_DEFAULT',
              nReturned: 5555,
              executionTimeMillisEstimate: 1,
              works: 5557,
              advanced: 5555,
              needTime: 1,
              needYield: 0,
              saveState: 12,
              restoreState: 12,
              isEOF: 1,
              transformBy: { address: { country: true }, _id: false },
              inputStage: {
                stage: 'COLLSCAN',
                nReturned: 5555,
                executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
                works: 5557,
                advanced: 5555,
                needTime: 1,
                needYield: 0,
                saveState: 12,
                restoreState: 12,
                isEOF: 1,
                direction: 'forward',
                docsExamined: 5555
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      nReturned: Long("5555"),
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: Long("15")
    },
    {
      '$group': { _id: '$address.country', count: { '$sum': { '$const': 1 } } },
      nReturned: Long("9"),
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: Long("15")
    }
  ],
  serverInfo: {
    host: 'ldp-2103',
    port: 27017,
    version: '4.4.6',
    gitVersion: '72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7'
  },
  ok: 1
}
```

Why the index is not used?
I've tried the same query using **mongodb-compass** and it clearly shows

> Index Keys Examined:0

Comment: Your index on 'address_country' has a _Collation_ specified. You need to use a collation in your query also to use the index ([collation and index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/collation/#collation-and-index-use)).

Comment: Yes, thank you: adding collation to my query didn't help, it only uses indexes when removing the collation completely from the index. However, I noticed that the index is used only on $sort but not on $group, so computing the number of elements for each index is slow...